# Deploy xml files during maven release

Tags: maven

During maven release process, maven will try to help you upload source, javadoc, and jar into nexus or artifactory, except those, I also want to upload something such as xml files.

Any one know how to config it? Maven deploy plugin seems very simple and dont provide such configuration for users.

Should I have to use deploy file goal instead? Or other ways?

Any comments are welcome.

Br,
Tim

Comment: Do you mean pom.xml files?

Comment: No, it will be updated automatically, I mean some other xml files, for example some special resource file that we hope it could be saved in the nexus server also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest solution for such things is to use the [build-helper-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/) like this:

```xml
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <!-- add configuration for antrun or another plugin here -->
      </plugin>
      ...
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>attach-artifacts</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <artifacts>
                <artifact>
                  <file>some file</file>
                  <type>extension of your file </type>
                  <classifier>optional</classifier>
                </artifact>
                ...
              </artifacts>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

You can also create a separate resources package and use it via maven-remote-resources-plugin in other projects.